# "Schiacciati come vasi di coccio": si tratta di un modo di dire? Cosa significa?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Leggendo questa [notizia su Euronews](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://it.euronews.com/2020/04/28/nel-2019-il-clima-ha-provocato-il-triplo-degli-sfollamenti-rispetto-alle-guerre&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjcj4nQ24rpAhW4BGMBHdJfBtEQFjAGegQIChAB&usg=AOvVaw2NzysUVe_mOxWWJ7n5f09C), mi sono imbattuta in questa frase (grassetto mio):

> Altri invece stanno cercando di tornare a casa dopo essere emigrati: i venezuelani in Colombia, per esempio, **schiacciati come vasi di coccio** tra due sistemi sanitari che non hanno i mezzi per assisterli durante la pandemia.

L'espressione "schiacciati come vasi di coccio" ha attirato la mia attenzione. Non sono riuscita a trovarla su nessun dizionario, ma una ricerca su Google ne dà parecchie occorrenze. Si tratta di un modo di dire o una frase fatta? Qual è il suo significato?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'immediato predecessore di questa espressione, che è presente a chiunque abbia fatto le scuole in Italia, è un passo dal primo capitolo dei *Promessi sposi* in cui si descrive la natura pavida di Don Abbondio, fattosi prete tutt'altro che per vocazione:

> Il nostro Abbondio, non nobile, non ricco, coraggioso
>   ancor meno, s'era dunque accorto, prima quasi di toccar
>   gli anni della discrezione, d'essere, in quella società,
>   **come un vaso di terra cotta**, costretto a viaggiare in
>   compagnia di molti vasi di ferro. Aveva quindi, assai di
>   buon grado, ubbidito ai parenti, che lo vollero prete.

L'immagine è però ben precedente: è presente in una favola di Esopo (la 354), ripresa almeno da Aviano e da La Fontaine.

Comment: Quindi, si tratta di qualcuno di molto fragile, di molto debole, in mezzo a esseri più forti, che possono "romperlo" con facilità. Ma, nella frase della domanda, i "vasi di ferro" sono i due sistemi sanitari: come dovrei interpretarlo?

Comment: Non ho capito bene quali siano i due sistemi a cui fa riferimento quell'articolo ma, sì, mi sembra che l'immagine sia usata con un po' di libertà, perché dal contesto pare che anche i sistemi sanitari se la passino male: il senso generale è di una persona o gruppo debole e povero preso in mezzo a persone o gruppi più potenti e solidi.

Comment: Non ne sono sicura, ma immagino siano i sistemi sanitari colombiano e venuezolano.

Comment: Ah, ecco, ha senso.